# Tkinter Python Pop-Up window that shows message but still lets another function run when pop-up is up.

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to have a "Downloading..." pop-up window show up as another function is running, and then when that function is done to close that pop-up window.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Are you familiar with the `Toplevel` widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import tkinter as t
from tkinter import ttk

root = t.Tk()
t.Label(root, text='Downloading...').pack()
pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, length=200, mode='indeterminate')
pb.pack()
pb.start()   
root.update()
```

This code will **immediately** display this window:

[image: tk download window]

Also, this won't stop execution... If you write more code below, python will continue executing your program; **but** there is a caveat - you have to call `root.update()` from time to time while you're doing something else, to allow tkinter to update the window, otherwise your window will seem frozen and the window manager will mark the window as "not responding".

Comment: Then to tear down I would just do pb.destroy?

Comment: @TrevorKruse No, `pb` is the progress bar inside the window. This simple example has only one window, the `root` window. Use `root.withdraw()` to remove the window from view.

Comment: @noskio Then I would need to use multiprocessing to update the bar correct?

Comment: @TrevorKruse No. You just call `root.update()` in your download code, from time to time. In my experience calling it every 50ms is enough, to get a 20FPS update. To answer your question, `multiprocessing` wouldn't work for this. The code updating the bar has to be in the same process that created the window, you can't do it from another process.

Comment: @TrevorKruse while you could use threads to do it, I wouldn't recommend it, because it adds complexity for no benefit. The best way is to use asynchronous download code, which allows you to context-switch to the gui update while you wait packets from the network, all in the same thread.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Tk() window and put a progress bar inside it.

Comment: If you already have a root window, you shouldn't be creating a second instance of `Tk()`.

Comment: I have used up to 5 instances myself without errors and cross window variables

Comment: I don't believe you, though maybe I misunderstand what you mean by "cross window variables". If you're talking about instances of `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc, it is literally impossible. If you just mean normal python variables, yes, you can have multiple Tkinter windows as long as you understand the limitations. It's just not something that should be taught to a beginner because there are trade-offs that are not very evident.

Comment: StringVar() I use crosswindow too, but my method of tkinter programming is somewhat unusual; I don't use OOP or classes

Comment: You might want to check that code -- each instance of `Tk` gets its own sandbox. Variables and widgets in one are literally invisible and inaccessible in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can find out how to create a popup window by searching StackOverflow for `[tkinter] pop-up window`.  When you have done that, here is a generic 'downloading' wrapper function.

```
def downloading(parent, function, args, kwargs):
    popup = <code or function call to create popup using parent)
    ret = function(*args, **kwargs)
    popup.destroy()
    return ret
```

`args` is a tuple or list of positional arguments.  `kwargs` is a key-value dict of keyword names and arguments.